# Getting the date_diff function return the difference in days

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I've been trying to build a feature to count the days it takes for products to be sold. We are selling unique items on behalf of our customers so it's good to know for reporting and product management purposes which items actually sell and how long it takes.

The custom function seems to getting the data for `$order_created_date` and `$product_date` OK and storing it in the order item meta, but actually calculating the difference in days is not working.

This is what I've achieved so far:

```
function mysite_woocommerce_order_completed( $order_id ) {
    //get order created date and order items
    $order = NULL;
    $order_created_date = NULL;
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $order_created_date = $order->order_date;
    $order_items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($order_items as $item_id => $order_item) {
        // addin _order_date meta not needed in finished version
        $product_id = $order_item['product_id'];
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_order_added_date', $order_created_date );
        // adding _product_published_date meta not needed in finished version
        $product_date = get_the_time( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $product_id ); 
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_product_published', $product_date );
        // calculate date difference, not working. Needs a check to not add the meta if already added because makes duplicate entries
        $diff = date_diff( $product_date, $order_created_date );
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_days_to_purchase', $diff );
    }
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'mysite_woocommerce_order_completed', 1, 1 );
```

Any help to solve the problem and recommendations to optimize the code would be appreciated. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo, I actually got it working. Had to use `new DateTime()`  with the variables and `$diff->days` to display the days. Now just to prevent the function from duplicating the meta information in the rare cases where some store manager changes the status by accident back and forth between completed and some other status. Ideas?

```
function mysite_woocommerce_order_completed( $order_id ) {
    $order = NULL;
    $order_created_date = NULL;
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $order_created_date = $order->order_date;
    $order_created_date = new DateTime($order_created_date);
    $order_items = $order->get_items();
    foreach ($order_items as $item_id => $order_item) {
        $product_id = $order_item['product_id'];
        $product_date = get_the_time( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $product_id );
        $product_date = new DateTime($product_date);
        $diff = date_diff( $product_date, $order_created_date );
        // +1 to days to start counting same day sales from 1 day
        wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_days_to_purchase', 1 + $diff->days );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'mysite_woocommerce_order_completed', 10, 1 )
```